# How to use column created from partition by clause to filter result in the main query?

Tags: sql

As I know, `SELECT` will only work on data that had been filtered by `WHERE`, and `HAVING` clause requires a preceding `GROUP BY`. However, I'm using `PARTITION BY` because I don't want to use `GROUP BY`, or more clearly, I don't want to group by those partitioned columns, but `GROUP BY` clause requires me to include all selected columns.

Therefore, I wonder if there is a way to use `PARTITION BY` clause to filter result, and more specifically, I don't want to put `PARTITION BY` in a subquery, then filter `FROM` the subquery. I wonder if something like this could work:

```
SELECT c1 
FROM t
WHERE RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY c2) = 1;
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Have you tried it? (Should take less time than asking this SO question.)